# Continuous analogue for Szpilrajn Theorem: complete preorder extends a continuous preorder

Tags: gn.general-topology, order-theory, continuity

A corollary of Szpilrahn Theorem states:

> Any preorder on nonempty $X$ has a complete and transitive extension.

I am thinking about the "Szpilrahn Theorem" for continuous preorder on nonempty $X$ with some suitable topological properties:

> Any continuous preorder has a continuous, complete and transitive extension.

For a simple example, consider $x,y\in\mathbb R^2$. Let $f$ be a continuous real function increasing on both arguments. Define a reflective and transitive relation $\succsim$ (aka preorder) satisfying:

1. $x_i\geq y_i$ for all $i$ implies $x\succsim y$; $x_i\geq y_i$ and $x_j>y_j$ implies $x\succsim y$
2. $f(x)=0=f(y)\implies x\sim y$
3. $f(x)\geq0\geq f(y) \implies x\succsim y$; if one of the inequity is strict then $x\succ y$.
4. $\succsim$ satisfies some forms of continuity

**Question:** does $\succsim$ always has a continuous complete preorder extension? If so what are some continuity conditions or further topological structure needed?

**Motivation**: The example is made by adding a "0" between $f(x)\geq f(y).$ Note that if the "0" is removed, then the preoder becomes complete.

**Related** There are several works on the continuous version of Szpilrahn theorem but they focus on [binary relation or partial order](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/On-the-continuous-analogue-of-the-Szpilrajn-Theorem-Herden-Pallack/00efee51bcc0f16e5f8b3c4c7ee61b749ba83784) without equivalence relation.

One other work [deals with preorder and total order](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Gianni-Bosi-2/publication/225215740_On_a_Possible_Continuous_Analogue_of_the_Szpilrajn_Theorem_and_its_Strengthening_by_Dushnik_and_Miller/links/00b4951d6720fc7b07000000/On-a-Possible-Continuous-Analogue-of-the-Szpilrajn-Theorem-and-its-Strengthening-by-Dushnik-and-Miller.pdf).